# Should I use Stream.CopyToAsync() to copy data from a network stream?

Tags: c#, stream, .net-standard, memorystream, networkstream

I am getting data from the `NetworkStream` of a `TcpClient` and I want to write the data into a fixed-length `MemoryStream`, because I know the size of the data.

I use `Stream.CopyToAsync` to write the data into the `MemoryStream`:

```
var result = new MemoryStream(size);
await ns.CopyToAsync(result);
result.Position = 0;

return result;
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs) of `Stream.CopyToAsync`, the method terminates when there is no data in the source stream. In my case, when the network connection is slow or interrupted, my method would return an incomplete `MemoryStream`.

Can I ignore this possibility or should I read the stream by my own since I know how much data will be sent?

Comment: `CopyToAsync` doesn't really relate to your problem, I don't think. Would the problem be different if you were reading chunks into a buffer and manually writing them to the `MemoryStream`? It seems to me that the real problem is that you don't know how many bytes you are selecting.

Comment: Since I know how many bytes will be sent by the server, I could repeat "read from source, then write into memorystream" until all bytes are received.

Comment: Then what stops you from checking that `MemoryStream` is the length you expect? If you get 0 bytes as the result of a read, the connection is closed.

Comment: I thought that when the connection is closed, `NetworkStream.Read` throws an `ObjectDisposedException`. Correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't it be totally possible that read returns 0 bytes even thought the connection is still open?

Comment: [`Read` blocks if there is no data (i.e. it waits for data).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958290/3181933)

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that, thank you for the clarification. Then `CopyToAsync` should be fine in my case. You can add an answer with a link to the source you just provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NetworkStream.Read` will block<sup>1</sup> until there is data and only return `0` if the connection is closed, I don't think this will meet your needs any better than `CopyToAsync`.

Since you already know how much data you're hoping to receive, I recommend just checking that the `MemoryStream` has the desired length:

```
var result = new MemoryStream(size);
await ns.CopyToAsync(result);

if (result.Length != size) {
     // it didn't load everything
}

result.Position = 0;

return result;
```

<sup>1</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958290/3181933